# Getting error 1004 on a vlookup on an userform vba excel

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

I need to enter a barcode on a textbox and use this to search a table; then use the search result as text on a different textbox.

what I have gives me a 1004 error-

What am I missing? Thanks!!!

```vb
Private Sub CodigoBarraEntradaTextBox_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

Dim CodigoEntrada As String

Set myrange = Range("Hoja2!A2:F2000")

If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then

'barcode to be entered on textbox

    CodigoEntrada = CodigoBarraEntradaTextBox.Text

'barcode is then used to search a value and placed said to a different textbox

    NombreProductoTextBox.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CodigoEntrada, myrange, 3, False)

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to [es.so] the official language of the site is Spanish, so please translate your question or ask it on [so] instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo haría así:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CodigoBarraEntradaTextBox_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

    'La variable Shift no la estás utilizando

    'Declaramos un array para meter el rango de datos
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim UltimaFila As Logn
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja2")
        UltimaFila = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        arr = .Range("A2:C" & UltimaFila)
    End With

    'Declaramos un objeto diccionario para almacenar la base de datos
    Dim BBDD As Object
    Set BBDD = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'Hacemos que la columna A de la Base de datos sea lo que se busca, y la C lo que se devuelve
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        BBDD.Add int(arr(i, 1)), arr(i, 3)
    Next i

    'Si existe el valor en la base de datos, devolvemos la columna C
    If BBDD.Exists(int(KeyCode)) Then NombreProductoTextBox.Text = BBDD(int(KeyCode))

End Sub
```

Comment: Damian, Muchas gracias!!

No había hecho nunca esto en vba y me parece mucho mejor. 
Te molesto una vez mas, si te ha pasado, tener un error 457, "esta tecla ya está asociada con un elemento de la selección"? No tengo valores repetidos y lo marca en la linea donde llenamos BBDD

De nuevo, muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Pues efectivamente tienes algún valor duplicado en la columna A de la base de datos, si pasas el ratón por encima de la `i` te dirá la fila del valor repetido.

Comment: Damian, muchas gracias! Efectivamente, todo lo que está después de la última fila con datos son vacíos idénticos!!! Tendre que identificar la última fila con datos y usar ese valor en el rango. Gracias!!!

Comment: @SebastianHernandez qué columna tiene siempre datos? La A?

Comment: Si, es donde están los codigos de barra

Comment: @SebastianHernandez acabo de editar mi respuesta, ahora ya debería funcionar. Si funciona, por favor, no olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta

Comment: Excelente, un pequeño typo en long, pero se corrige solo.  https://drive.google.com/open?id=11nA-Y47ey6JejpkaSMsPUFC1sFMxLgos  el archivo. No logro que los datos se vean en el textbox. Sigo buscando pero muchisimas gracias por el nuevo enfoque!!!

Comment: @SebastianHernandez es probable que se estén mezclando `Strings` con `Longs` así que he hecho que todo sean números. Prueba el código editado a ver si funciona.

Comment: Damian, eras la paciencia personificada!! cambié la linea:
  If BBDD.Exists(int(KeyCode)) Then NombreProductoTextBox.Text = BBDD(int(KeyCode))
por
If BBDD.Exists(Int(CodigoBarraEntradaTextBox.Text)) Then NombreProductoTextBox.Text = BBDD(Int(CodigoBarraEntradaTextBox.Text))
Está funcionando así (ya se que no soy prolijo, hace casi 15 años que no programo nada!!)